# Spring Webflow DataBinding to immutable objects via a constructor?

Tags: spring, immutability, spring-webflow

Is there any way of using an immutable object as a model within a view-state in Spring webflow? I know Spring webflow generally tends towards setters for this kind of thing, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a custom DataBinder or WebDataBinder that could handle binding the data using a constructor?

I'm also aware there's this [(SPR-1488)](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-1488) JIRA task against the problem, which advocated direct field access. Do people advocate this way of doing things? To me it doesn't quite feel right.

Thanks,

Stuart

Comment: I'm also trying to work this out.

Comment: See my solution. I too was wanting this feature.

Answer (score 2):

I have put an example of how you can do this using Jackson's ObjectMapper (which besides JSON does a good job mapping anything to immutable objects ).

https://gist.github.com/4458079

A couple of things to note is that you can't use `@ModelAttribute` if you want to use Spring's validation (`BindingResult`) unless you replace all the argument resolvers. However `@Valid` (with validation) should work and `@RequestBody` will also work (with out validation) with my solution.

Although its using Jackson to map request parameters to objects there is no JSON processing involved. If you want that see [MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html).

As a feeble shameless plug I needed this in conjunction with my [Immutable ORM called: JIRM](https://github.com/agentgt/jirm) as I prefer immutable objects for message driven architectures.