# Immutable objects and Spring/Spring MVC: the right choice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I usually try to design my classes as *immutable classes*, so I have a lot of advantages in terms of coding stress.

But working with Spring, I sometimes notice that the framework "discourages" this kind of design in most cases, in favour of classic *JavaBeans* design: **default constructor + getters/setters**.

I really don't like *JavaBean* designed objects because of their *insane* mutability.
So I'm wondering if I'm missing something...

I try to keep my classes design as elegant and reusable as possible, but a framework requires to change this design or allow it in a difficult way...

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Spring doesn't en- or discourage anything in general so I wonder why you think this. There is nothing preventing you from doing constructor injection in beans instead of setter injection (you could do field based injection also). The only place where you would need getter/setters is when doing data binding in the web layer however that goes for all web frameworks including JSF, Struts etc.

Comment: I take you have web binding in mind and not bean creation, right?

Comment: If you are worried about the view-model classes bound to forms being mutable, Spring allows you to use immutable view-model classes as well.  You will have to write code for converting form fields into model objects.  You will need to write classes for every model class that you populate from form fields.  This will mean you will need to weigh the advantages of immutability v/s the advantages of auto form binding provided by Spring MVC with mutable objects.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, I'm talking about data binding on web layer side, but also on model/persistence side.

Comment: @davioooh The model persistence side is not handled by Spring, so the complaints on the front should be geared towards current ORMs. When it comes to the web binding, then yes out of the box there is no support for immutability, but you could write your own code for cases where you need it

Comment: Well actually there is support for immutability as you can configure the `WebDataBinder` to use direct field access instead of bean properties. The same goes ORM providers which have a configuration option to either do field binding or bean property binding (if I recall in JPA the default depends on where you put your annotations field or setters). So yes you could do everything without, easily, modifiable objects, but it requires additional work. Next to that IMHO you shouldn't use your ORM classes in your web layer.

Comment: @M.Deinum the reality is that not enough frameworks leverage http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html `@ConstructorProperties` and require the bean being created first and then the properties set. Really there is very little reason why Spring cannot use `@ConstructorProperties` which was designed for this reason.

Comment: Correct and which is available now in Spring 4.1. Spring exists for over 10 years and you are pointing to features that aren't available that long (since java 7). However as I mentioned before it isn't only Spring MVC that suffers this fate I would argue that every web framework out there suffers from this.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think your confused. There are two types of databinding that the OP did not really disambiguate. There is the typical DI which spring does great and then there is FORM post web databinding which as far as I know does not leverage `@ConstructorProperties` but might in 4.1. Plus `@ConstructorProperties` has been around since JDK 6 so I don't know what recent means to you.

Comment: No I'm not confused :). I stand corrected about 1.7 being 1.6 your link threw me off guard. I could swear that I have seen commits in Spring 4.1 regarding `ConstructorProperties` and data binding (but I must have dreamt that couldn't find them back). Although I can imagine that that would be problematic especially with complex objects/nested paths.

Comment: Yes when I tried to write the patch it was too hard as I would have had to rewrite almost all of Springs Property Binder. Jackson though has far superior databinding (its more than just a JSON lib) so I ended up using it to do the immutable databinding. Sorry about the link to the wrong version.

Answer (score 2):

Well for web form databinding (ie form POST) the issue is that Java reflection is weak on constructors thus it is difficult to do databinding without annotations. A long time ago I contemplated filing a bug that Springs data binding should leverage the oft forgotten [`@ConstructorProperties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html) (iirc I looked into doing the patch myself but it was rather complicated and would break many things). Someone should probably file a feature request.

BTW I'm talking about web databinding (and not dependency injection) because Spring has for a long time had great support for constructor based DI (immutable objects need constructor based injection). In fact I would say constructor based injection or (static method factories) are becoming the preferred practice over traditional getter/setter components (you can see this in many Spring classes changes over the years moving toward final and constructors).

Anyway I was able to do web data binding with immutable objects using Jackson https://gist.github.com/agentgt/4458079

(Although its using Jackson for databinding the request does not have to be in JSON)

You might also want to see [Spring Webflow DataBinding to immutable objects via a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066405/spring-webflow-databinding-to-immutable-objects-via-a-constructor/14166334#14166334) where I original came up with the gist and has more info.

Comment: Spring doesn't really have a preference apart from the fact that, especially lately, required dependency are injected through constructor arguments instead of having it as an option (and later checking in the `afterPropertiesSet` method of `InitializingBean`).

Comment: I say preferred as I have noticed in projects like Spring AMQP, Spring Integration, and the new Spring Boot to use constructor based injection or something similar and using `final` fields. Given todays JVM memory model and push for massive concurrency I would say in general most Java programmers are moving towards immutable compared to 6 years ago where it was hardly done.

Comment: Agree. But from what I see that is only for required dependencies or for those which there isn't a default. But maybe that is more apparent nowadays especially when using configuration classes.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes create separate  immutable "design model" classes and mutable (Java Bean) "MVC model" classes to avoid those kinds of problem.

Answer (score -2):

It uses Dependency Injection to inject objects into other objects. So if these other object is immutable it can't change their state.

Comment: This is not true because dependencies can be injected as constructor arguments, keeping all Spring managed beans immutable.  Setter (property based) injection (that makes objects mutable) becomes useful when there are legitimate scenarios requiring cyclic dependencies (`A` depends on `B` which in turn depends on `A`).

Comment: What about using annotations like @Autowired?

Comment: @manish I wouldn't call cyclic dependencies a legitimate scenario but a design smell...

Comment: Agreed, but there are valid scenarios where cyclic dependencies would be required.

Comment: A cyclic dependency is a no go in my book and generally an issue of bad design (or ancient libraries).